# data structure time complexity solve problem

Tags: c, time-complexity, big-o

I want to make sure that it's the right answer.
answer :

```
T(n) = (n log n +1 ) 
big 0 = O(n log n)
```

```
sum = 0;      ---- 1
for( i=1; i<=n ; i*=2) ---- log n ? 
 for(j=1; j<=n ; j++) --- n 
   sum++; ----1
```

Comment: There's no data structure here, just loops.

Comment: But your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. The number of iterations of the **outer loop** is the index of the most significant bit in `n`. So, it is indeed *floor(log<sub>2</sub>(n))*
2. The number of iterations of the **inner loop** is exactly *n*.

Then, the total number of iterations of the body of the **inner loop** is *n * floor(log<sub>2</sub>(n))*, the test, increment and body all execute in constant time.

Hence, the time complexity of this code is **O(n.log(n))**